# $f, g$ are continuous mapping from a connected set $S$ onto $\mathbb{C}^*$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f, g$ are  continuous mapping from a connected set $S$ onto $\mathbb{C}^*$

If $f^n=g^n$ for some positive integer $n$,

1.what is the relation between $f,g$?

2.If $f(x)=g(x)$ for some $x\in S$, what can be said about $f,g$ Then?

3.Show that $\mathbb{C}^*$ can not be replaced by $\mathbb{C}$ in the hypothesis.

Well, my guess is $f=ge^{2k\pi i\over n},k=0,1,n-1,$ for $1$, but I have no idea for the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right: You can argue as follows: 
(1) Let $h = f/g$ (note that $g(s) \ne 0$ for all $s \in S$, hence $h$ is well defined). Then $h$ is continuous and has $h^n = 1$. So $h[S] \subseteq \{\exp(2k\pi i/n)\mid 0 \le k < n\}$. As $h[S]$ is connected, we must have $h[S]  =\{\exp(2k\pi i/n)\}$ for some $k$, so $f = g\cdot \exp(2\pi i k/n)$.

(2) Now, as there is $s \in S$ with $h(s) = 1$, arguing as in (1), we have $h[S] = \{1\}$, so $f= g$.

(3) Let $f,g \colon [-1,1] \to \mathbb C$ defined by $f(t) = t$, $g(t) = |t|$ for $t \in [-1,1]$. Then for each $t \in [-1,1]$ 
$$ f(t)^2 = t^2 = |t|^2 = g(t)^2 $$
so $f^2 = g^2$, but $f \ne \pm g$.