# If for two complex-valued continuous functions $g_i$ it holds $g_i(0)=1$ and $g_1^n=g_2^n$, can we infer that $g_1=g_2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function, radicals

Remember that if $a\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, then $\phi\in\mathbb R$ is called *argument of $a$* if $$a=|a|e^{{\rm i}\phi}\tag1.$$ Let $$\operatorname{Arg}a:=\left\{\phi\in\mathbb R:\phi\text{ is an argument of }a\right\}$$ and $\arg a$ denote the unique intersection point of $\operatorname{Arg}a$ and $(-\pi,\pi]$.

> **Question 1**: Are we able to show that $\operatorname{Arg}a^n=n\operatorname{Arg}a$?

It should hold, since we should have $$\phi\in\operatorname{Arg}a\Leftrightarrow a=\left|a\right|e^{{\rm i}\phi}\Leftrightarrow a^n=\left|a^n\right|e^{{\rm i}n\phi}\Leftrightarrow n\phi\in\operatorname{Arg}a^n\tag2.$$

---

Now, if $n\in\mathbb N$, remember that $z\in\mathbb C$ is called *$n$th root of $a$* if $$z^n=a\tag3.$$ Let $$\sqrt[n]a:=\left\{z\in\mathbb C:z\text{ is a }n\text{th root of }a\right\}.$$

> **Question 2**: Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space and $g_i:E\to\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ with
>
> 1. $g_i$ is continuous;
> 2. $g_i(0)=1$.
>
> If $g_1^n=g_2^n$, are we able to infer that $g_1=g_2$?

I know that it holds that whenever $f_i:E\to\mathbb C$ is continuous and $e^{f_1}=e^{f_2}$, then $$\exists k\in\mathbb Z:f_1-f_2=2k\pi\tag4.$$ So, if $f_1(x_0)=f_2(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in E$, then $f_1=f_2$. Maybe we can reduce the desired claim to this situation.

On the other hand, it should hold $$\sqrt[n]a=\left|a\right|^{\frac1n}e^{{\rm i}\frac{\operatorname{Arg}a}n}=\left|a\right|^{\frac1n}\left\{e^{{\rm i}\frac{\arg a+2k\pi}n}:k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\right\}\tag5.$$ So, unless I'm missing something and if the answer to Question 1 is positive, it should hold $$\sqrt[n]{a^n}=\left|a\right|e^{{\rm i}\frac{\operatorname{Arg}a^n}n}=\left|a\right|e^{{\rm i}\frac{n\operatorname{Arg}a}n}=\left|a\right|e^{{\rm i}\operatorname{Arg}a}=a;\tag6$$ from which the desired claim should follow even without assuming that $g_i$ satisfies (1.) and (2.). Am I missing something?

Comment: $(-1)^{2}=(1)^{2}$ but $-1 \neq 1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: $g_i(0)=1$ is given in Question 2.

Comment: @MartinR I am talking abut the question in the title. I am taking constant functions as  a counter-example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm sorry, I simplified the title too much. However, I see that you gave a (trivial) counterexample to $(6)$. Do you see which equality in $(6)$ is wrong?

Comment: $\operatorname{Arg}a^n=n\operatorname{Arg}a$ fails as soon as the right-hand side is outside of $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Comment: Question 2 is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/534444/42969

Comment: @MartinR No. "Arg" here doesn't mean what it usually does; see the definition above.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Do you think the claim is valid with the given definition of "Arg"?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I just wanted to accept your answer after I've verified your arguments, but noticed that you've deleted it. Was there some issue in the argumentation?

Comment: No problem with the proof. I will be thankful if you approve it.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Not sure which claim you're asking about. Yes, if $Arg$ is defined to have values in $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ then $Arg(zw)=Arg(z)+Arg(w)$; in my book, as it were, that's sort of the good reason for defining $Arg$ that way, not that anyone does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin R has already commented on the first question.

Answer fo quesion 2): Any normed linear space is (path) connected. So  the range of $\frac {g_1} {g_2} $ is a connected set contained in the $n-$th roots of unity. Hence, $g_1=cg_2 $ wher $c$ is an $n-$th root of unity. Since $g_1(0)=g_2(0)$ we get $c=1$.

Comment: Question 2 is already answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/534444/42969

Comment: Connenetdness of a nls is worth pointing out.